# linking specific page of document with pdfpages' linktotoc option

Tags: hyperref, labels, pdfpages, links, ref

i am wondering if there is an easy way to link a specific page of a document added via pdfpages.

for example if i have:

```
\includepdf[addtotoc={1, section, 1, sectionname, sectionlabel,
                      10, section2, 1, section2name, section2label}]{document}
```

for example if i want to link the fifth page in section 1, i've tried

```
\hyperref[sectionlabel.5]{some text}
```

but that doesn't work (with or without link=true as an added argument)

i really like the tidiness of the addtotoc approach, and i don't want to start hacking down the pdf for pages i would like to label.

is it possible i'm overlooking something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option `link` of `\includepf` to create link destinations for each page. The name of the links if `<filename>.<page number>`. With `\hyperlink` you can reference these links:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\hyperlink{dummy.pdf.3}{See page 3.}

\includepdf[
  pages=1-5,
  link
]{dummy.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Your approach using `addtotoc` creates links as well, but only for those pages which appear in the TOC. All other pages are not linked. The name of the link then is **exactly** the name used in `addtotoc`. You can *not* add a page number like you can do with `link`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\ref{sec:BBB}

\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={1, section, 1, AAA, sec:AAA,
            5, section, 1, BBB, sec:BBB}
]{dummy1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hi, thanks, one more question: do addtotoc and link work together? or shouldn't they work together. i'm curious if using the 'pages=-' command is the reason i couldn't link a specific page.

Comment: thanks for sharing your example. turns out if i added link=true,linkname=diffLabelfromToc and use hyper*link* instead of hyperref, it works! ty ty!

Comment: Yes, you can combine `addtotoc` and `link`.

Comment: matthias i have a slightly bigger challenge for you, if you don't mind. i'm being greedy and i want this functionality across documents using xr-hyper. is it possible to use hyperref to jump to a page named from a pdfpages link in a foreign document? it seems not, but i thought maybe an enthusiast like yourself could help propagate this 'feature request' (hey, it's a community). it works fine for addtotoc labels, just not link.

Comment: You do not need anything special. With `\href` you can already link to all defined destinations in a PDF. The syntax is `\href{<file>#<dest>}{<text>}`. The names of the destinations that pdfpages creates are the same as the names of the links used in LaTeX. Thus to link to a document called `foobar.pdf` with a destination `dummy.pdf.4` use `\href{foobar.pdf#dummy.pdf.4}{let's go}`. BTW, hyperref inserts destinations like `page.1`, `page.2`, ...

Comment: that sounds like it's within a document though, right? i tried the \href example and it doesn't seem to work when i have two separate documents, each with their own set of pdfpages. for example if i tried to link to one.pdf that included somename.pdf from a separate file two.pdf, i used \href{one.pdf#somename.pdf.4} and it took me to one.pdf but didn't jump to where somename.pdf.4 would be. could you elaborate on the hyperref destinations bit? maybe that would work. right now the (cross-file) hyperref only works for the toc entries

Comment: also mb it's mac thing: but trying to click href link on mac the first time will give a permissions error, then it'll jump to the right file (but again not the right spot, even if i use the same file for <file> and <dest>). i understand that precise page-linking across documents is probably not easy. i should be happy it goes to the right section (hence why i said i'm being greedy)

Comment: The command `\href{one.pdf#somename.pdf.4}{...}` is correct. The link should get you to this specific page, and not to the first page. But note: It you used `linkname` to change the name of the link/destination, e.g. `linkname=xox`, then you must use this name in the `\href` command too, e.g. `\href{one.pdf#xox.3}`.

Comment: omfg i didn't tex it enough times but it works now. omfg this is gonna really put me over the top matthias thanks man

Comment: oh my god matthias. all of canada's "left-leaning" MLSE-loving sycophants are irate. you do not know what you have done! thank uuuuuu